# Angular2 Nested Components : Error: core_2.Input is not a function Error loading http://localhost:9080/app/boot.js

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have 3 components.
1. rubric editor
2. rubric criteria editor
3. rubric descriptor editor

rubric editor is the main component which is loaded in the router outlet. rubric editor loads rubric criteria editor which expects an Input object, and rubric criteria editor loads rubric descriptor editor which expects an input Object.

but this, doesnt works. and I get the core2.Input is not a function error on the @Input line in rubric descriptor editor. (The error blocks boot.ts and nothing runs)
Full Stack Trace:

```
Error: core_2.Input is not a function
    Error loading http://localhost:9080/app/boot.js
Stack trace:
.execute/RubricDescriptorEditorComponent<@http://localhost:9080/app/components/rubric/rubric-editor-descriptor.js:44:21
.execute@http://localhost:9080/app/components/rubric/rubric-editor-descriptor.js:37:48
ensureEvaluated@http://localhost:9080/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:2981:5
ensureEvaluated@http://localhost:9080/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:2973:11
ensureEvaluated@http://localhost:9080/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:2973:11
ensureEvaluated@http://localhost:9080/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:2973:11
ensureEvaluated@http://localhost:9080/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:2973:11
bootstrap/</</</</</<.execute@http://localhost:9080/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3099:13
doDynamicExecute@http://localhost:9080/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:715:20
link@http://localhost:9080/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:908:20
doLink@http://localhost:9080/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:569:7
updateLinkSetOnLoad@http://localhost:9080/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:617:18
proceedToTranslate/</<@http://localhost:9080/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:430:11
run@http://localhost:9080/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:138:14
zoneBoundFn@http://localhost:9080/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:111:14
lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch@http://localhost:9080/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1511:16
lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback@http://localhost:9080/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1523:17
lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish@http://localhost:9080/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1494:11
[4]</</</<@http://localhost:9080/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:243:5
run@http://localhost:9080/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:138:14
zoneBoundFn@http://localhost:9080/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:111:14
lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush@http://localhost:9080/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1305:9
```

I am not really sure why this error comes up. I have a very same code in another component, and it works fine.

Why I am trying to do this? I need to take some data as input from the user, and it forms a double nested json structure.

here is my code from the rubric-descriptor-editor.ts:

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';
import {
    RouteConfig,  ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router,
    LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy
} from 'angular2/router';
import RubricService from "../../services/rubric-service";
import {Rubric} from "../../models/rubric";
import {Input} from "angular2/core";
import {Criteria} from "../../models/criteria";
import {Descriptor} from "../../models/descriptor";

@Component({
    selector: '[myDr]',
    templateUrl: './app/components/rubric/rubric-editor-descriptor-form.html',
    directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class RubricDescriptorEditorComponent {
    @Input('myDr') levDesc: Descriptor;
    constructor (public rubricService: RubricService, public router:Router ){
    }
}
```

the template for this Component:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="6" placeholder="Descriptor "
         #descriptor="ngForm"
         [(ngModel)]="levDesc.descriptor"
         ngControl="descriptor" ></textarea>
```

for my rubric-criteria-editor:

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';
import {
    RouteConfig,  ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router, RouteParams,
    LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy
} from 'angular2/router';
import RubricService from "../../services/rubric-service";
import {Rubric} from "../../models/rubric";
import {Input} from "angular2/core";
import {Criteria} from "../../models/criteria";
import {Descriptor} from "../../models/descriptor";
import {RubricDescriptorEditorComponent} from './rubric-editor-descriptor';


@Component({
    selector: '[myCr]',
    templateUrl: './app/components/rubric/rubric-editor-criteria-form.html',
    directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, RubricDescriptorEditorComponent]
})

export class RubricCriteriaEditorComponent {
    @Input('myCr') crit: Criteria;
    //
    constructor (public rubricService: RubricService, public router:Router, params: RouteParams ){
        console.log('params.get("id") : ', params.get('id'));
        if (params.get('id') != null) {
           // this.crit.levels = new Array[4];
        } else {
            console.log('Entered RubricEditor add mode');
            //this.crit = new Criteria(null);
            //this.crit.levels = new Array[4];
        }
    }

}
```

the View Tempalte:

```
<td>
    <button class="close removeCriterion" >&times;</button>
</td>
<td>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Criterion Description"
              #description="ngForm"
              [(ngModel)]="crit.description"
              ngControl="description"
    ></textarea>
    <input style="margin-top: 10px" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Weight"
           #weight="ngForm"
           [(ngModel)]="crit.weight"
           ngControl="weight"
    />
</td>
<td *ngFor="#lev of crit.levels" [myDr]="lev"></td>
```

Comment: I can't figure out exactly where the error is coming from but here are couple of things to try: you can't use variable decorated with `@Input()` in `constructor()`, you have to 'wait' for it to bind - it's available in `ngOnInit()`; try using Elvis operator in your templates `<td *ngFor="#lev of crit?.levels" [myDr]="lev"></td>`. Hope it helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the TypeScript compiler.

I managed to work around it by importing the required in one statement instead of using multiple import statements.

`import { Component, View, Input, Output } from 'angular2/core';`

When using the debugger, it shows that core_1.Input exists, but core_2.Input doesn't.

Comment: True. I solved some of my errors like this.. m still not sure if the nested nested components will still work. But,  yes In most cases I found the issue with having multiple import statements from the same path.